# SIMD 256i only processing 4 elements

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics, avx, avx2

My understanding is that m256i operations can operate on 8 32-bit integers at once. I made a simple program in visual studio that looks like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main()
{

    alignas(sizeof(int)) int32_t test0[8] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 };
    alignas(sizeof(int)) int32_t test1[8] = { 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 };
    alignas(sizeof(int)) int32_t delta[8] = { 0 };
    __m256i* src0 = (__m256i*)(&test0[0]);
    __m256i* ref0 = (__m256i*)(&test1[0]);
    __m256i* delta0 = (__m256i*)(&delta[0]);

    *delta0 = _mm256_sub_epi32(*src0, *ref0);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, only the first 4 elements of delta are updated - the other 4 remain 0. I get the same behaviour in x86 and x64 build. Is there some issue here I'm not aware of to get AVM to work?

Comment: I actually found the problem happened on a much simpler case when I went to create a simplified example. Attached the code I'm running.

Comment: OK but I couldn't reproduce it, is there a particular way to compile it that matters, or a particular version of the compiler? What I get is: in debug mode, it just works (with any setting for ARCH), in release mode the code is considered dead and omitted. IDK if maybe you're running into a premature `vzeroupper` (or a proper one, but your breakpoint is hit after it) or something weird like that but it didn't happen to me

Comment: hm no I just made a new project in VS2015, added a main.cpp and added the code above.

Comment: Your arrays are under-aligned, you should be doing `alignas(__m256i)` or `alignas(32)` if you want to point a `__m256i*` at it and deref.  Or use `_mm256_loadu_si256` to do alignment-not-required loads.  This wouldn't explain seeing zeros, though, you'd expect a fault if the compiler made asm that required more alignment than it created.  Sounds like your compiler is broken, or you're using options that make it generate wrong code for AVX2 stuff.  (Harold's suggestion of a stray `vzeroupper` seems most likely; include the compiler-generated asm and compiler version/options in your question.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/G5Eec1K8W shows VS2015 MSVC's code-gen for your code.  Looks ok to me.  All your arrays are big enough, and the asm is using YMM regs with no vzeroupper.

Comment: I switched to VS2019 and its working now. Not sure why.

Comment: If you want to know what's going on, look at the asm the compiler generates.  (e.g. single-step with the debugger and switch to asm view, or disassemble, or compile with options that make it generate asm instead of object files.)  That should show you what nonsense the old bad compiler got up to.  Or just keep using a newer compiler that doesn't destroy your data, or even better use clang.